# Unable to capture variables in SAML response body using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, saml

I have question about how to extract the SAML Response in jmeter, i follow these steps but it's not succeed and i don't know where is the problem :
- when i have the login Page, i send post request to the Idp provider to authenticate me (i give him, username and password), after that i will get SAML Response like this :

```html
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
```

- In jmeter i used: post regular expression extractor, i give him this regex to extract the SAMLResponse but it don't work : 
  name='SAMLResponse' value='([^"]+)'

If anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This response is base64 encoded. You need to base64 decode this response. Save the response in a file, lets call it idpResponse.

If you have a linux shell run the command below to decode the response:

```
 cat idpResponse | base64 -D
```

You contents are:

```
  <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
  xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
  Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:obtained"
  Destination="https://asfv2-sarah-dev.cfapps.renault.fr/saml"
  ID="idaegi4-OfUpt3t6MeWvFhU4ovNfM"
  InResponseTo="ID_3c62dc6a-297f-4361-ba87-b1f6f1bfa53a"
  IssueInstant="2016-04-25T11:33:10Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer>
    https://virtual872.labtech.pls.renault.fr:8443/nidp/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID="idoEAaiOJruD0lvAFvcPGTxA4GZV8"
    IssueInstant="2016-04-25T11:33:11Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml:Issuer>
      https://virtual872.labtech.pls.renault.fr:8443/nidp/saml2/metadata</saml:Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <ds:Reference URI="#idoEAaiOJruD0lvAFvcPGTxA4GZV8">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>
            JCZ165dScExJIQRJ1G/WcBGrcrg=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
        vRmUL8JH4zbU+nMwb9OuVJFYAchodke2E3HJzpbaQBwvFG3fzVMeyWsmgiZYOFG0R9N++yZod0gi
        6SEanBEFUMZNrT5YRaEyR6Y7N6Jp5VHS0/YUcjujt7LHOihEgHY7geNMGq9yNFH37aFH6U3xfP42
        qfuFAPHgwcLwBj1PgTwIm5FS05I8p/vUBbGb3RTjZlmotDvfXqHrelPsw6niPEi6I7SN7KNtVZUs
        tA4bRgTcufgKMEVUhwV+ZvIJDfSV1ZgbuUp9GzRxtUbJnkNPob9it4z5LxQLARtZ+h/XxLJe4kHq
        VaCUd4aZQGSikGujErPVUIxKQpGJzdOETKUS9Q==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
            MIIFWTCCBEGgAwIBAgICAg4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwRTEQMA4GA1UECgwHUmVuYXVsdDExMC8G
            A1UEAwwoQ2xhc3MgMSBBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiBQcmUgUHJvZHVjdGlvbiBDQTAeFw0xNTA3MDIx
            NTQzMDRaFw0yNDExMTYxMDUwMjBaMEsxEDAOBgNVBAoMB1JlbmF1bHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkZSMSow
            KAYDVQQDDCF2aXJ0dWFsODcyLmxhYnRlY2gucGxzLnJlbmF1bHQuZnIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
            AQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDZt4GCZUe8szuK3iM/C0S7udZU65kej3Pii9Bv2IH/htPLTgDgxX/b
            WLwUfCTRJ48IldsMeYjKqPeRAvNr9Dr/HXfHEG4sSopjIw0a0+GRQrwvycTlx0bN40CDlEQzaRxO
            awjf5YUXgCuvdY98F1vwpr1o8d4h3VQ0jUWCQZpdHMNz3FqxsCwpWz89JTjs7d7k/T9skgfPpc4R
            BXhNNV0DqT4pSLFBZijsNHgSpGsZ10+7PAd3NQyARbys/NthrR3VL7HLTJ7XcdJmSCJYf/3xtCkl
            XVrmBZC0eVGW2O6Au9PaG4EfFv/wpLuc5d1dpBEZFfqm8G1cGPF8FOkOxRn/AgMBAAGjggJLMIIC
            RzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUcN9ay5TA5Ke6Z7clTMyAHYpNHvEwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUo7dspiMVtOjlt/9E
            Pq8/RHUFz3kwgewGA1UdIASB5DCB4TCB3gYKKwYBBAGqEQQQATCBzzBvBggrBgEFBQcCARZjaHR0
            cDovL2NybC5yZW5hdWx0LmZyL0NlcnRpZmljYXRpb25Qb2xpY2llcy9SZW5hdWx0SW50ZXJuYWwv
            Q2xhc3MxQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25QcmVQcm9kdWN0aW9uQ0EucGRmMFwGCCsGAQUFBwICMFAaTlJl
            bmF1bHQgSW50ZXJuYWwgQ2xhc3MgMSBBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiBQcmUgUHJvZHVjdGlvbiBDQSBD
            ZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIFBvbGljeTARBglghkgBhvhCAQEEBAMCBsAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUH
            AwIGCCsGAQUFBwMBMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIF4DAlBgNVHREEHjAcgRpkaWRpZXIucm9tZWxvdEBy
            ZW5hdWx0LmNvbTBYBgNVHR8EUTBPME2gS6BJhkdodHRwOi8vY3JsLnJlbmF1bHQuZnIvQ1JML1Jl
            bmF1bHRJbnRlcm5hbC9DbGFzczFBdXRoUHJlUHJvZHVjdGlvbkNBLmNybDBTBggrBgEFBQcBAQRH
            MEUwQwYIKwYBBQUHMAGGN2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwucmVuYXVsdC5mci9vY3NwL1JlbmF1bHRJbnRlcm5h
            bFByZVByb2R1Y3Rpb24wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAE1DcpWVnVN5bvZBqFkjUV1zQioU/yE0
            F6YVOn8NGvul3dgUInpDAu528CGU3mf4Wkwyg/AcicvuK+jbf6SNzuoqcCDjbqa6WaKFDHMgj1VD
            GrfYBw/WddNG/t8DNcaJbmvW68F1W0NL1DwVDgfAQ+pWd/s64fFssm8rdYkf9KwzLPXKYIn74Ybr
            +Ff+xfTXeU4aXkP57Z3IceoHVvgXmcByJA3jaY+Mt+c4At0sDgccozEK2XNXtN30ts0s2bxcU/NC
            7URFJN0FO6xG7YoH2ba3ItJUzQyds4fxWT1Z97ghpx4dz9c9uw0xbBXhpVtBVvn9oL9BP4uGcLZa
            ZveLyIM=</ds:X509Certificate>
          </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <saml:Subject>
        <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
        NameQualifier="https://virtual872.labtech.pls.renault.fr:8443/nidp/saml2/metadata"
        SPNameQualifier="https://asfv2-sarah-dev.cfapps.renault.fr">
        p080145</saml:NameID>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">

          <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ID_3c62dc6a-297f-4361-ba87-b1f6f1bfa53a"
          NotOnOrAfter="2016-04-25T12:33:10Z"
          Recipient="https://asfv2-sarah-dev.cfapps.renault.fr/saml" />
        </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml:Subject>
      <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2016-04-25T11:28:11Z"
      NotOnOrAfter="2016-04-25T11:38:11Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestriction>
          <saml:Audience>
          https://asfv2-sarah-dev.cfapps.renault.fr</saml:Audience>
        </saml:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml:Conditions>
      <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-04-25T11:33:10Z"
      SessionIndex="idoEAaiOJruD0lvAFvcPGTxA4GZV8">
        <saml:AuthnContext>
          <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
          urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
          <saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>
          secure/name/password/uri</saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>
        </saml:AuthnContext>
      </saml:AuthnStatement>
      <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="uid"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          p080145</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="preferredLanguage"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          FR</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="mail"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          sarah.hadbi@renault.com</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="givenName"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          Sarah</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="sn"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          Hadbi</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="cn"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">HADBI
          Sarah</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="renpersontype"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          ou=catSTGR,ou=PersonTypes,ou=TechnicalData,o=renault</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="Role1"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          admin</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Name="rencostcenter"
        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

          <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
          AA50815</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
      </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
  </samlp:Response>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you give me a way to decode it in linux, but i don't know how to decode it in jmeter, so if you know please answer me

Answer (score 0):

Your regex, `name='SAMLResponse' value='([^"]+)'` mixes quote types: `'` and `"`. Your matching group matches "anything that isn't a `"` one or more times, and then a `'` afterwards. I suspect that your pattern matches the trailing `'`, keeps going, and then can't find the ending `'` **because it already matched it in the** `([^"]+)`.

If you're passing this value back into another request, that should be all you need to change. Otherwise, you'll have to do what [Suresh Koya suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36854804/4324778).

Comment: First, Thank you for your answer,  but i don't understand exactly what you suggest me, my question is : for you what is the regular expression to use in my case to get the SAMLResponse ? and after that if i get the SAMLResponse how to decode it to base 64 in jmeter.

Comment: Without seeing the entire response, I can't be certain what your regex should be, but I suspect it should either be `name='SAMLResponse' value='([^']+)'` OR `name='SAMLResponse' value="([^"]+)"`.

The `^"` means "not a double quote", but your regex ends in a single quote (`'`). Notice that my suggestions are simply 'be consistent with your quotes.'

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

> name='SAMLResponse' value='([\s\S]+?)'